# jboss Services which failed to start

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x, hibernate-5.x

During deployment to jbosss 7.2.final, the ear project received the following error exception:

```
JBAS014777: Services which failed to start: service  
jboss.persistenceunit."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-
ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in
service jboss.persistenceunit."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-
ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU": java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

This error happened when I upgraded hibernate 3 to hibernate 5 in the `pom.xml` file.

All Exceptions from log file

```
16:14:30,049 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 312) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU": java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more

16:14:30,055 FINE  [javax.xml.bind] (MSC service thread 1-7) Trying to locate morfeusflex/service/billingaddress/jaxws_asm/jaxb.properties
16:14:30,056 FINE  [javax.xml.bind] (MSC service thread 1-7)   not found

16:14:30,435 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 309) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/ClientStateSavingPassword -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0"."Morfeusflex-web-1.0".env.ClientStateSavingPassword
16:14:30,435 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 309) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/jsf/ProjectStage -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0"."Morfeusflex-web-1.0".env.jsf.ProjectStage

{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU\": java.lang.AbstractMethodError


16:14:31,954 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 313) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0.ear/Morfeusflex-ejb-1.0.jar#MorfeusflexPU": java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99)
    ... 4 more

16:14:32,507 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 308) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/ClientStateSavingPassword -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0"."Morfeusflex-web-1.0".env.ClientStateSavingPassword
16:14:32,507 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 308) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/jsf/ProjectStage -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module."Morfeusflex-ear-1.0"."Morfeusflex-web-1.0".env.jsf.ProjectStage
```

Please have a look and provide me solution

Comment: You get an AbstractMethodError when the method has changed between compilation time and runtime. In your case this may be a change within Hibernate (as you upgraded to version 5). Please search in your log file for _all_ exceptions and post them. There should be another stacktrace for the AbstractMethodError.

Comment: Please look at those exceptions.

Comment: OK. The error appears in `org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)`. Which exact version of Hibernate 5 are you using? Does your ear contain hibernate jars or have you set the scope of the jar to `provided`?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 5.0.2.Final version. Only javaee-api's scope is provided

Comment: In Hibernate 5.0.2.Final the line 303 of SessionFactoryImpl is an empty one. By the way, you cannot change the Hibernate version only by changing the version in your project. You can read more about class loading in JBoss AS here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7.